# Ajax doesn't send data and doesn't show any alerts

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, post

I have a problem with ajax. I asked once about ajax but now my code can't send Data or even show alert. This code don't do anything. Only in web console in Data tab at "laravel-session" after click button to send it's changing data

```
    $('#saveBtn').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("test");
            $.ajax({
              url: "/ress/Add",
              method: "POST",
              data: $('#addForm').serialize(),
              dataType: 'text',
              success: function (response) {
                alert("test3");
              }
            });
            alert("test2");
        });
```

This code shows only alert with (test) and (test2) no (test3) even when in code is error function. I dig whole internet to find solution and still without results. (on submit) or other function doesn't work too. I can answer for any solutions if I tried this or other

[image: POST]

It now send correctly But I think It's not open route file, because in route file with that I have to add some data to database

Comment: Do not alert in the click, use console.log instead - test if /ress/add returns anything by looking in the network console

Comment: what's you network tab showing in browse?

Comment: Check your `network` tab instead of `console` tab of your browser

Comment: It shows POST with 419 and I get in error: error: function (request, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
          }

unknown status

Comment: Please add the error message from your network tab so we can help you

Comment: you can post your code on pastebin which creates an issue. This way we'll get better idea

Comment: I just edit my post, and add screen what I have in that. It Still doesn't add data to my database because it doesnt execute route file with /res/add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check error part of ajax, So that you can get what is the error.

```
 $('#saveBtn').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("test");
        $.ajax({
          url: "/ress/Add",
          method: "POST",
          data: $('#addForm').serialize(),
          dataType: 'text',
          success: function (response) {
            alert("test3");
          },
            error: function (err) {
               alert("in error");
           }
        });
        alert("test2");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get a 419 status that means that route is protected with authentication.